# Replacing a pdf

Tags: files

I am looking to delete a file permanently.

It says that is is not being used in any places and I have deleted it, but it is still showing up. I want to replace it, but Drupal just keeps making a new version.

I've even tried to redirect to a newer version of the file but it still doesn't work.

Please advise.

Comment: It says? What's it? Which version of Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a php function (via devel, Drush or DrupalConsole) `file_delete($fid)` to remove the file from the server. Then your redirect will work.
Also it's helpful to read through this [ticket](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2648816) if you have the time and the patience.